# access variable outside of class definition

Tags: class, coffeescript

I need to access a variable outside of the class definition like in the example below.

```
module.exports = (config) ->
    class Foo
        constructor: () ->
            console.log config

    return Foo
```

But if I try to create an instance of that class, the variable is undefined and can not be printed.

```
Foo = require('./foo.coffee')(config)
bar = new Foo()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is valid CoffeeScript and works for me. Perhaps you have an error somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Better try this:

```
module.exports = 
    class Foo
        constructor: ( @config ) ->
            console.log @config
```

With the calling looking like this:

```
Foo = require('./foo.coffee')
bar = new Foo(config)
```

I have used `@config` in this case, but you could also use `config`.